# Cakephp best way to create secret input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Okay so i have a combobox with two options.

Now if one of the options is selected a new input field should appear.

```
        echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array( 'id' => 'groupId'));
    echo $this->Form->input('clientid',array( 'type' => 'hidden', 'id' => 'id_client',));
```

And for that i would use Jquery to check the values

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#groupId").change(function () {
            if($(this).val() == 2){
                // do set visible
            }
        })
      });
</script>
```

My question is: how can i change the type of the field to visible? i have tried:      `$('#groupId').show();` also `$('#clientid').get(0).type = 'text';`

But didnt seem to work and i am starting to wonder if this is the best way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Secret = not editable? If you want to save data that is supposed to be neither visible nor editable, dont use the form in the first place. Read about "Default Values – hidden" [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

`type="hidden"` is not appropriate to hide UI elements (form fields or anything else).

You should instead use the CSS attribute `display`. Change your `clientid` input type to `"text"`. When `groupId` is not 2, set `display: none` on your `clientid` input. When it's 2, set `display: block`.

With jQuery, you can use `$('#clientid').show()` and `.hide()`.

For instance:

```
<select id="groupId"><!-- options... --></select>
<input type="text" id="clientId" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showHideClient() {
    var show_client = $(this).val() == 2;
    $("#clientId").toggle(show_client);  // hide or show
  }

  // we bind the "change" event to the hide/show checking
  $("#groupId").change(showHideClient);
  // and we call it at page load to hide the input right away if needed
  showHideClient();

});
</script>
```

Comment: should i add the css directly to the element or should it be in a seperate file?

Comment: `.toggle()` adds the CSS automagically in the element `style` attribute. But you may need to hide the input at page load (because the selected option may not be 2 right from the start). I'll update my answer to something more complete.

Comment: when i toggle the field name stays (the input field disapears but the label stays)

Comment: There is no magic. You asked JS to hide the input, not the label. You have to choices: wrap your label + field in a div and hide/show the div, or add your label to the selector, eg. `$('#clientId, #labelClientId')`.

Comment: added a modification to the div tag making it hidden when document i loaded thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).attr('type',  'text');
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Marc wants. Seems he just needs to show/hide the input if the right `<select>` option is selected. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. i had stuck a lot for solving this problem